# In Windows 7 ,After turning on the snmp service and creating a java agent using snmp4j i get this error

Tags: java, snmp

What should you do when you get a null pointer exception even after starting the SNMP service?

Comment: We don't call that a question. Make sure you add enough details so anyone reading it can understand what is the problem.

Comment: Question:When  I tried to run a snmp4j library code on an IDE I got a nullpointer exception.I turned on the snmp service on my PC What more should I do?? Is There a step that i missed?

Answer (score 0):

1.First Turn on SNMP service from start->Turn windows Features on or off
2.Goto Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services->(Check Whether SNMP service has started)Right click on SNMP Service
3.Click on Properties
4.Security->Add->Edit Community&Rights According to your Requirements.

Comment: That's not a good answer either. Steps might help others resolve the problem, but you might also state clearly why the steps are needed.

Comment: After turning on the snmp service you have to follow the steps given above.